# NXP kinetis chip to drive UART RX on Digital SX Pro

Tags: uart, driver, mosfet-driver

I have connected a NXP kinetis development board to a digi six pro development board via UART ports.
Originally I thought I could directly connect the RX and TX lines but found communication to the digi sx UART in was sporadic.
Upon further examination I find that when the line was high it was only at 3v rather than 3.3, and when it was low, it only went down to 2v.

In conclusion, I believe I need some sort of line driver but I'm unsure what is most commonly used and am looking for recommendations.

Thank you.

Comment: did you connect the grounds?

Comment: Yes I connected the grounds.